# Gallary Image Cicular in android

Tags: android, imageview

This adapter is useful for circular image view but the circular image view can be possible from right to left,not possible with left to right so please suggest me that what should i write in this code so image can be view circular from left to right also ??

```
public class ImageAdapterCircleGallery extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    int itemBackground;

    Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,
            R.drawable.img3, R.drawable.img4, R.drawable.img5,
            R.drawable.img6, R.drawable.img7, R.drawable.img8,
            R.drawable.img9, R.drawable.img10, R.drawable.img11,
            R.drawable.img12, R.drawable.img13, R.drawable.img14,
            R.drawable.img15, R.drawable.img16, R.drawable.img17,
            R.drawable.img18, R.drawable.img19, R.drawable.img20,
            R.drawable.img21, R.drawable.img22, R.drawable.img23,
            R.drawable.img24, R.drawable.img25, R.drawable.img26,
            R.drawable.img27, R.drawable.img28, R.drawable.img29,
            R.drawable.img30 };

    public ImageAdapterCircleGallery(Context c) {
        mContext = c;

        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        a.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return getPosition(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getPosition(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        /*ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        position = getPosition(position);
        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        return i;*/

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        position = getPosition(position);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(90, 90));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);

        return imageView;

    }

    public int checkPosition(int position) {
        return getPosition(position);
    }

    int getPosition(int position) {
        if (position >= mImageIds.length) {
            position = position % mImageIds.length;
        }
        return position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use my Code for Rounded ImageView. It ensures that whatever image you set in it, it will be perfectly rounded :-

```
package com.example.listviewwithimages;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return; 
    }
    Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();


    Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
            sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
//    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
//            sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth()/2, sbmp.getHeight()/2,
            (sbmp.getWidth()/2), paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


            return output;
}

}
```

and in your xml, use it like this :-

```
 <com.example.listviewwithimages.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="Big Image" />
```

in your Adapter, inside getView()

```
        RoundedImageView imageView = new RoundedImageView(mContext);
```

Comment: I just told above. It is a whole class. Wherever you want to use rounded imageview, dont use the normal ImageView tag. Use the above tag. Instead of ImageView, the whole package+class name will go in the xml

Comment: how to pass the image on that, i want only limed images to show in aciivity

Comment: How to pass image? Are you new to android ?just use background property or setImageBackground of imageview like you used to do for a regular ImageView

Comment: in image adapter we have to set image in getView() but using above code where i have to set setImageBackground of imageview

Comment: I have editted my code. please have a look. All the methods will work anywhere. MY code will give you a  circular imageview only. Whatever image you set in it, it will be cropped from corners and will appear as round to you

Comment: Please pass the reference id of the roundedimageview from the xml in oncrreate method where you have declared the object for roundedimageview using findviewbyid method. Also place the roundedimageview class code in a separate class file